# How can I POST data in form html with EMPTY action?

Tags: post, action

How I can post the data in post from in html without action setted?

Here is the code:

```
<form name="form_upload" id="form_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="[var.path_to_upload_script]" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
```

So is there any way I can send the data to `[var.path_to_upload_script]` with blank action? I mean like that `action=""`

And the whole row looking like that:

```
<form name="form_upload" id="form_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
```

I know something must be added above but i don't know what so the form will send the data to `[var.path_to_upload_script]` with action blank.

So is there any way? I already tested `onSubmit=""` but it's not working.

Comment: With a blank action attribute (or if it's omitted) the form will submit to itself by default. If you need to leave out the action attribute for some reason, but have the data sent elsewhere, you'll need javascript or jQuery or similar to handle the form submission.

Comment: Yes i have javascript to handle this submition, but how i can send this data to the javascript with empty action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following

```
<form name="form_upload" id="form_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" onsubmit="return myfx(params);">
   Put you fields here
</form>
```

And you function should be like

```
function myfx(params)
{
  if(ok)
  {
     //Print via PHP
     document.forms[].action = "<?php $path_to_upload_script; ?>";
     //Using a js variable, in this case the variable must be set somewhere
     document.forms[].action = path_to_upload_script;
     return true;
  }
  else
  {
     do anycoding 
     return false;
  }
}
```

It can be a php or javascript variable, but it must be set in the action line.

No Validation of the form

```
    function myfx(params)
{
     //Print via PHP
     document.forms[].action = "<?php $path_to_upload_script; ?>";
     //Or
     //Using a js variable, in this case the variable must be set somewhere
     document.forms[].action = path_to_upload_script;
     return true;

}
```

Comment: This should send the data to `[var.path_to_upload_script]` like action?

Comment: What is [var.path_to_upload_script] a Javascript Variable or PHP. Where this is coming?

Comment: `$path_to_upload_script      = '/cgi-bin/uu_upload.pl';` I think it's a PHP Variable

Comment: I placed this :

    `function myfx(params)
    {
      if(ok)
      {
         //Print via PHP
         document.forms[].action = "<?php $path_to_upload_script; ?>";
    
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
    }`

And now it's even not starting upload.
I think i make mistake somewhere..

Comment: Oh, you may need to customize the schema i posted, for example, ok variable do not exist, it should be a validation variable you have. if the logic goes into return false; it will not go anywhere.

Comment: if you just need it to go somewhere without validation, recheck post again.